# IPS LCD Left-side Interlaced Dark Pixels

Tags: video, lcd, distortion

I purchased three i2367fh IPS panels from AOC a few years ago, one of which had a leaky backlight; But once that was replaced, the new panel began intermittently mudding up the video signal on the left side.  AOC wouldn't respond to my warranty requests, and now I'm stuck with it.
It appears the problem affects every other pixel row of the display, which starts around the middle and gets worse when approaching the left side.  Oddly enough, the area of the display that is affected by this problem also suffers some kind of electronic burn-in!  I have attempted to recreate the symptoms in this image, which should be viewed at a 1:1 ratio:

[image: LCD Problem Example]

The exact colors aren't the same as they appear up-close on the monitor, but the effect from 1:1 ratio view is essentially the same.

So far I have swapped the video cable, tried both analog and digital signals, swapped the power supply, and swapped the main controller.  The only parts left in question are the board soldered onto the panel and the panel itself.  I would prefer not purchase a new LCD.  I can solder and I am familiar with basic electronic components.  Does anyone know where I should start if I were to pursue this problem further?

Edit: I also should mention that the back-lighting is correct on the monitor.

Comment: Cool how you recreated that.  Could it be caused only by the backlight not exisitng in that area, knowing that the backlighting is "polarised" by the linear diffusion that spreads it, and that polarisation is used on the lcd pannel types?  That the lines are completly related to the darkening in that area?

Comment: @Psycogeek That's a good suggestion, but I forgot to mention that I already checked that.  I pulled the LCD off and the back-light is even.  Thanks though!

Comment: I take it you have substituted one of the other displays for the apparently faulty one and it does not show the same symptoms? Otherwise I would wonder if you had the display output set to 1080i instead of 1080p. Looking for a dry solder joint would not be much fun, even with a suitable microscope.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I don't think my graphics cards are capable of interlaced output, but that still wouldn't explain why it is only on half the screen.  These symptoms appear regardless of the resolution or computer.  Even at lower resolutions, the problem occurs as if the resolution was native - probably because the controller board (which is working) does the up-scaling.